# Swift using annotation callout to call segue

Tags: ios, swift, view, mkannotation

I am working on an App where you can see some pins/annotations and when you click them they show some information about that place. What I want to do is add a button so when the user clicks the "callout" it activates a segue which will open a new View with more detailed information.

I have my code and functions but it seems to be an error, because when I click the button to run the segue, the App crashes. My code is the following...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var pin = MKPointAnnotation()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

        //Adding information to my Annotation
        let pinCoordenadas = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(25.589339000, -100.257724800)
        pin.coordinate = pinCoordenadas
        pin.title = "Christus Muguerza"
        mapView.addAnnotation(pin)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
           if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
            print("Not MKPointAnnotation")
            }

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "identifier")
             if annotationView == nil{
                 annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
                 annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
                 annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
               }
               else {
                 annotationView!.annotation = annotation
               }
        annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "curz")
        return annotationView
    }

    var anotacionSeleccionada : MKPointAnnotation!

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        anotacionSeleccionada = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "vista", sender: self)
    }
}


      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
           if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController {
           destination.pin = anotacionSeleccionada
            }
       }

}
```

The errors...[image]

[image]

I hope you guys can help me out, I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outlet to your `mapView` seem to be broken, since your program crashes on the first row in `viewDidLoad`. Do this to solve this issue:

1. Go to your storyboard
2. Right click on your map
3. Remove the outlet/outlets if you have by mistake created more than one
4. Remove `@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!` from your code
5. Create a new outlet
6. Run your code again

**The  issue was that OP had both the mainView and the detailView connected to the file viewController. I created a new file for OP called DetailController and linked the second viewController and now it´s working.**

Comment: I did what you said, The second error is gone,  but it still says fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)  in mapView.delegate = self.

Comment: Do you think the functions I added (mapView func) have something to do with this problem?

Comment: I think your functions are ok. Do you have the possibility to zip your project and upload it on Dropbox/Google Drive and I´ll take a look at it @DanielC. Because I copied your code here and did as I wrote in my answer and it worked fine for me. Try to clean your project and restart Xcode.

Comment: Sure! I´ll send it right away! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DanielC. you issue is that you hade both the mainView and the detailView connected to the file viewController. I created a new file for you called DetailController and linked the second viewController and now it´s working. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6y7q0m8vzj2r881/CUSTOMANNOTATION.zip?dl=0) is a working example of your project.

Comment: Thank you so much! it is working now! I really thank you for taking your time to help me with this issue. you're the best bro :D

Comment: @DanielC. np glad to help.